# using cudaFree to free gpu memory in different devices

Tags: cuda

can i use cudaFree to free gpu memory allocated in another device like

```
cudaSetDevice(0);
cudaMalloc(&devPtr, size);
cudaSetDevice(1);
cudaFree(devPtr);
```

if my system supports unified virtual address space?(cuda ver9.2)

Comment: Not everything is unified by default. You need to allocate it with `cudaMallocManaged()`, so in your example, CUDA will error because you are not using unified memory.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: That is not correct AFAIK. In unified addressing the API is aware of which device a pointer resides in and managed memory is certainly not required in this us case

Comment: @talonmies you are right. I was certain I had an error yesterday related to this, but I am wrong, it must have been for some other unrelated issue. Still, OP is not allocating managed memory, right? I am wrong stating that it will error, but not wrong saying OP its not allocating managed memory.